# How to handle many-to-many relationship with OOPHP?

Tags: php, oop

Whats the best way to go about many-to-many relationships in object-oriented PHP.

If I have three tables, books and categories and the join table bookscategories (handles many to many), should I create a model/class called bookcategories and handle everything to do with the book-category relationship there?

My specific questions with reference to the psuedo code below are:

1. Have I correctly assigned the methods to the appropriate classes?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this that isn't very complex?
3. In which class does one handle the linking relationship? e.g. $book->link_to_cat('5')?
4. Any caveats for using this approach (if applicable).

Any advice is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Pseudo Code:

```
<?php

class Books {
    //handles all book table stuff

    public function delete_book() {
        //deletes specific book
        //deletes all related bookcategories using find_by_book_id
    }
}

class Categories {
    // handles all category stuff
}

class BookCategories {

    public static function get_cats_by_book_id {
        // sql join statement to retrieve category objects by book id
    }

    public static function get_books_by_cat_id {

    }

    public static function find_by_book_id() {
        //returns bookcategories by book id.
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Personally, I'd ditch the `BookCategories` class - it's an unnecessary implementation detail.  Just add a `get_categories()` method in the book class and a `get_books()` method in the category class.  Or, put code in each constructor to pull up all the linked books / categories when you create a category / book object.

Comment: Why your class names are in plural?

Comment: @Sam - would you recommend that even if BookCategories have additional properties, such as BookCategory assign_date, assigned_by_user, etc.

Comment: @Marc - was a mistake in the psuedo code. Thanks for being sharp!

Comment: @Nick - Yes.  As far as a Book is concerned, each Category will only have 1 assign_date, assigned_by_user, etc associated with it.  When I think of objects, a Book and a Category are straightforward; what exactly is a BookCategory?  Is there ever a situation where you would care about a BookCategory except as related to a Book or to a Category?

Comment: @Sam - ok great.  So if there was a meaningful relationship like ClassEnrollments (learners >- classenrollments -< classes) would it be worth having a class or would you still recommend keeping methods to individual classes?

Comment: @Nick - I don't think you'd ever really need to create a class for a relationship like that.  The only reason you need to have a separate table for one:many or many:many relationships is because of the quirkiness of relational databases; there are other storage schemes where the relationship table wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You might find investigating design patterns helpful. The composite pattern is often used in this situation. A good book to help you with design patterns with php oo is Matt Zandstra's
[PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice](http://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-5-Objects-Patterns-Practice/dp/1590593804/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1294999874&sr=8-5)

Comment: Thanks - I bought it yesterday after checking some reviews.  Great suggestion!  Thank you so much!